# Postgresql内で、データベースに入れません。

Tags: linux, sql, postgresql, virtualbox

https://github.com/blobmon/simplechan
ユーザーでデータベースに入りたいのですが、入れません。

> Now, once you are back again being the normal, default user, `cd` into `/sql/` directory in Simplechan repository. We are going to create tables and functions now.
> Try opening `psql` with the latest created db and role. In my default case, I try opening psql with `simplech_db` and `simplech_role`.
>
> `$psql -d simplech_db -U simplech_role`
>
> Create tables by importing those sql files now. Type these commands...
>
> `\i create_table_query.sql`
> `\i functions.sql`
> `\i functions_moderator.sql`
>
> Make sure those sql statements were imported and executed without errors. If there are errors, make sure to fix them. I think an error might come when you type `\i create_table_query.sql` with extension `uuid-ossp`. It can be easily fixed by installing some extra postgres package. Any other error you might encounter, should be easily fixable.

個々の部分ができません。ユーザーからデータベースに入って、tableを作り、sqlファイルを作りたいので、そこまで手順を教えてください。
ちなみに、「simplech_db and simplech_role.」←これはvirtualbox内のLinuxじょうでやるんですか？それとも、SQL　Shell上で行うのですか？

Answer (score 1):

引用されている`README.md`の箇所の前段に、手順が記載されていると思います。

> Install postgresql database server in your machine. Make sure it is version 9.5 or great.
>
> After installing postgresql, open command line and enter these commands line-by-line making sure you are doing correctly every time... This command is for opening psql with default postgres user. Just typing psql while being normal user will fail because postgres user requires postgres db to open. It is extra step which postgresql people might have avoided. But it is needed for security I think.
>
> `$sudo su - postgres`
>   `$psql`
>
> Once you are inside psql, create a role and a database with your desired name. In default case, I have used simplech_role and simplech_db for role and database name respectively. Type these commands...
>
> `CREATE ROLE simplech_role WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB LOGIN;`
>   `CREATE DB simplech_db WITH OWNER simplech_role;`

なので、PostgreSQL 9.5以上をインストールした状態で、

- Linuxシェルから、`sudo`と`psql`を実行。
- psqlのプロンプトから`create ROLE`と`CREATE DB`を実行。

したあとに、引用した箇所のコマンドを実行すればよいと思います。

#### 追記

PostgreSQL 9.5でdatabase作成の手順を確認してみました。
`create DB`はsyntax errorになるようです。(短縮表記はないようで)

```
create database simplech_db WITH OWNER simple_role;
```

と実行する必要があるようです。

ですので、databaseの作成に失敗しており、そのせいで`psql -d simplech_db -U simplech_role`に失敗しているかも知れません。
database「`simplech_db`」が出来ているかどうかは、`psql -l`で確認できます。

```
$sudo su - postgres
$psql -l
```

出来ていれば出力に`simplech_db`が見えると思います。

Comment: データベースとユーザーは作れたのですが、そこからそれに入ることができません。$psql -d simplech_db -U simplech_role　これを入力してもできません。ほかのコマンドを使わないといけないのでしょうか？